# PDF download on iPad is invalid

Tags: java, ipad, jboss, pdfbox, pdf.js

I'm displaying a pdf using pdf.js. I can then click to download the generated pdf (generated by pdfbox) or click to email it to a designated email address.

On a computer, this works fine, the pdf has merged fields (filled in with pdfbox), I can email it and the file is fine, download it and it isn't corrupt.

On an iPad, I can initiate the email, and the file comes over just fine (confirming that the generated PDF is perfectly fine.), but when I click to PRINT it, the PDF is rendered in CHROME and the merged fields are NOT there.

If I click 'Open with..' and open it with a separate app like Adobe Reader, I am told that the file is invalid - only on the iPad using Chrome.

I don't think this is a pdf.js problem. Is there any reason why downloading a pdf created by pdfbox in Chrome on an iPad would be corrupt/invalid?

Functionally, everything should be exactly the same whether these things are being done on a desktop vs ipad.

Comment: If you share the PDF, I (or some other people) might tell you whats wrong with the file. Maybe this will bring you slightly forward.

Comment: Btw are you sure that you generated the file with "PDF.js"? I thought this is a viewer only.

Comment: Sorry, viewing with pdf.js and generated with pdfbox

Comment: Then you should really share the PDF, and of course edit the question. And mention what version of PDFBox you are using (hopefulle 1.8.7 or higher). If you can't share the PDF, then try to create a "minimal" PDF that you can share. Try also 1.8.8 https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.8-SNAPSHOT/ as we recently improved field related stuff.

Comment: Thanks Tilman. For whatever reason, we're using 1.8.2, I will try upgrading asap and see if that resolves anything.

Comment: I just realized what this must be. I don't think the iPad can few these forms correctly becuase of the merged fields. Those fields are the only things missing from the pdf if viewed in a browser! So not a pdfjs or pdfbox problem!

Comment: but you said you're getting an error when opening with Adobe Reader...

Comment: Yeah, I guess I misspoke saying it wasn't pdfbox. I tihnk there must be something wrong with displaying the pdf/opening the pdf after pdfbox sets all the field values. I did upgrade to 1.8.7 and there is no change. If I try to open the pdf in a browser on the ipad, the file shows but the fields where i set values are not there. If i open it in a different app (adobe reader, pdf max etc), i am told the file is corrupt.

Comment: That is why I asked for the file... if it is a bug (and it seems so), the PDFBox folks can only fix the bug if they get to see the file.

Comment: Ok I will create a sample one. How can I attach it to this question?

Comment: upload them to a public place, e.g. dropbox and then put the link here.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8vvv8qrtaos0fu/test.pdf?dl=0 -- merged form fields are set to read only, values are set using pdfbox

Comment: I can open it with adobe reader. It does not claim that the file is corrupt. GSView can also open it.

Comment: If you open the pdf in chrome on the ipad, do you see the test values i set on the first page (NINE, TEST)? I do not see them in Chrome, however it is opening in reader for some reason as you said, without being marked corrupt, with the test fields i set

Comment: I don't have an ipad. I answered because you said it wouldn't render in Adobe Reader. Btw please try also the version 1.8.8 (see earlier comment). If it still doesn't work, ask on the pdfbox user mailing list, there's one guy who is an expert on acroform. https://pdfbox.apache.org/mailinglists.html

Comment: Ok, to clarify, reader on a desktop opens the file. It is broken on  ipads. I will try 1.8.8